# How to stop RecyclerView from overlapping TextView when scrolling Android TV

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout, android-tv

I have an Android TV app that has a RecyclerView below a TextView. Everything looks great until I click down to the third item which causes the RecyclerView to cover the TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/homeHorizontalMargin"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
        
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_below="@id/dateTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/epgRVHorizontalMargin"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I stop the RecyclerView from overlapping the TextView?

Comment: Your recycler view is inside the relative layout. So, to avoid complexity, you should remove `app:layout_constraint...` attributes from recycler view which would be required if its parent were ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Okay, I did remove the app:layout_constraint... parts from RecyclerView, but that didn't solve the overlap problem.

Comment: "until I click down to the third item" - do you mean it happens when you scroll down the recycler view and get to the third item?. If possible, can you please share the screenshot of the output?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecyclerView` parent layout has below property

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
```

So, when you scroll `RecyclerView` it will overlap with other view in layout.

You can remove it. Why you use this property here is there any specific reason to design other view in screen?
or you have `ConstraintLayout` as root layout so why you add `RelativeLayout` again and put `RecyclerView` inside this layout.

You can design your XML layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/homeHorizontalMargin"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/dateTV"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/epgRVHorizontalMargin"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dateTV" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```